Open Activities with No Group ID" Error in Team Screens Batch (Guidewire PolicyCenter)
I'm encountering the error " open activities with no group ID" in the logs. After investigating, I found that it originates from an out-of-the-box Guidewire batch process in PolicyCenter called Team Screens. Unfortunately, I don't have access to the source code since it's OOTB. I've already validated that the Activity.AssignedGroup is not null, but I'm trying to understand why this result is occurring. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

There could be an issue with the data, where the Activity.AssignedGroup field is set, but the corresponding group record is missing or has been deleted. I would recommend to examine a sample of the activities that are causing the error. Look for any patterns, such as specific users, teams, or types of activities that are more prone to this issue.

It will be a little hard for anyone to pinpoint your issue. You may want try assigning the activity to a different group and see if you still get the error. I think that this batch process posts this log message once and will say "Found X open activities with no group ID" for the total number of activities in with a null group ID. Are you saying you checked every open activity in PC and all have a non-null groupID?
This KB article seems to indicate that the groupID must be null for this error to occur. Login required for this link.
https://partner.guidewire.com/s/article/What-statistics-does-Team-Screens-batch-process-create

dripps   I am looking into AssignedGroupID field in Activity table , hope this is same as  group ID , then i am good and found out the root cause  :)

Was the root cause that the AssignedGroupID was null for some open activities? If not, then please post the root cause.

Yes I run the query for Activities with AssignedGroupID as null and found  couple of entries .same number is showing batch also . Hopping both are picking same entries .
